# Error: expected unqualified-id before 'bool'

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I am a beginner attempting the last c++ exercise problem in this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/12974/
It's called Graduation.
After starting to code it, I decided to separate a class definition into a header file. (keep in mind this if the first time I have ever defined my own header file. ever) I tried to define a member function of the header file class in main.cpp, but returns an error.

Here is the operator function definition that gives the error:

```
//in main.cpp
Bunny::bool operator>(const Bunny &comparison) //ERROR!!! expected unqualified-id before 'bool'
{
    if (badbunny == false && comparison->badbunny == true)
        return true;
    if (badbunny == true && comparison->badbunny == false)
        return false;
    else if (badbunny == comparison->badbunny) {
    //......blah..blah..blah....nothing special here
}
```

Here is the header class definition:

```
//in Bunny class.h
class Bunny
{
public:
    const char * name;
    const char * color;
    int age;
    char sex;
    bool badbunny;
    Bunny *next;
    //default constructor
    Bunny();
    Bunny(char * M_color);
    //operators
    bool operator<(const Bunny &comparison);
    bool operator>(const Bunny &comparison);
};
```

However, when I type the class definition (and some other declarations from the header file that I didn't type here) straight into main.cpp and don't bother with any header files, my compiler doesn't give me any errors.
As you can see, "bool operator>(const Bunny &comparison);" is clearly declared in the header file. Why can I not access it from main.cpp?
I clearly #include'd "Bunny class.h" in main.cpp, and the header file has a guard and everything.

Comment: `Bunny::bool operator>(...` should be `bool Bunny::operator >(...`

Comment: @WhozCraig well it got rid of that error, got a shitload more later in the program though XD. Just wondering, why do I have to write it this way, when I can write Bunny:bool operator without any problem, but only if I type the class definition in main.cpp?

Comment: Because you have to tell the compiler the namespace context of the operator you're defining *somehow*. it may sound trite, but that is simply how the language works. By doing what I described you're telling the compiler "this is the `bool operator <` function I declared in class `Bunny`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed in your declaration of the function:

```
Bunny::bool operator>( ... )
```

The correct way to do it is:

```
bool Bunny::operator>( ... )
```

with the `Bunny::` belonging to the *function name* rather than the return type.